# Специализация шаблона класов. Как специализировать только одну функцию

Tags: c++, visual-c++, шаблоны-с++

Вот хочу сделать шаблонный класс и в нем хочу, чтобы все работало как надо, только одна функция, чтобы при char* работала иначе, как и конструкторы. Но не хочу полностью переписывать весь клас под char*.
Как это делается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вполне можно написать метод класса для определенной специализации без переписывания всего класса и с использованием любого стандарта:

```
template<typename T> class
foo
{
    public: void
    bar(void) { ::std::cout << "normal" << ::std::endl; }
};

template<> inline void foo<char *>::
bar(void) { ::std::cout << "special" << ::std::endl; }
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aXs5HQI3eEQ2xqM6)

Answer (score 0):

Ну, если с использованием C++17, то напрашивается простейший способ - `if constexpr` - что-то вроде

```
template<class T>
struct Test
{
    T t;
    Test(T t):t(t) {
        cout << "Test::Test\n";
    }

    void out()
    {
        if constexpr (is_same_v<T,const char*>)
        {
            cout << "out(const char*)\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "out(T)\n";
        }
    }
};


int main()
{
    Test<int> i(5);
    Test<const char*> c("");

    i.out();
    c.out();

}
```

Comment: я думал, что можно как-то перегрузить функцию под определенный тип T

Comment: @Dim, перегрузка функций работает по собственным параметрам, а не параметрам класса, т.е. перегрузить можно, но только в том случае, если у функции есть параметры, по которым перегружать. Специализаций для функций нет, поэтому если Вам реально нужна специализация, то способ представленный Harry является наиболее простым в реализации, если можно использовать C++17. Если нельзя, то можно использовать tag dispatching для достижения того же эффекта.