# Хочу специализировать в шаблонном классе конструктор с параметрами (конструктор присваивания)

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Суть вопроса указана в заголовке. Вот ошибка, которую получаю:

> Error  C2244   'Pair::Pair': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

Вот сам код:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Pair
{
    char* key;
    T value;

    static int count;

    bool nameIsNull(char* name)
    {
        return (name == NULL || name == nullptr);
    }
public:

    Pair() : value(0), key(nullptr)
    {
        count++;
    }

    Pair(T value) : value(value)
    {
        setKey()
        count++;
    }

    //Pair(char * value);
    //Pair();

    //setters
    void setName(char*& name1, char* name2);
    void setValue(T value) { this->value = value; }
    void setKey(char*);


    //getters 
    T getValue() const { return value; }
    char* getKey() const { return key; }
    static int GetCount() { return count; }



};

template<typename T>
int Pair<T>::count = 1;

/*
** class Pair for typename char*
*/

template<> 
Pair<char*>::Pair() : value(nullptr)
{
    count++;
}


template<typename T>
Pair<char*>::Pair(T value)
{
    value = nullptr;
    setValue(value);
    count++;

    std::cout << "uniform\n";
}
```

Comment: Дубликат [Специализация шаблона класов. Как специализировать только одну функцию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/830467/Специализация-шаблона-класов-Как-специализировать-только-одну-функцию).

Comment: "Конструктор присваивания"??? Что это такое?

Comment: Непоеятно, почему водном конструкторе используется список инициализации, а в другом вдруг - присваивание. Два разных человека писало?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
template<>
Pair<char*>::Pair(char* value)
{
    value = nullptr;
    setValue(value);
    count++;

    std::cout << "uniform\n";
}
```

Comment: Не поверите, хотя думаю поверите. До этого писал в такой же форме и не работало, теперь работает. Просто жизнь боль, а программирование магия (ну или я невнимательный)